# Trying to Change a Select Number of Words in a Column Into a Different Word Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I am currently trying to create a macro that will look down an entire column, and if the word equals a certain word, it would then be changed to the more appropriate word.

For example, every time the animal 'Bird' was located in column B, it would be turned into the word 'Parrot'. If, while searching down column B, it came across the word 'Dog' or 'Cat', the word would remain the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: `Range.Replace` with a loop over two arrays, one of the searchTerms, and one of the replaceTerms. Or use a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: A basic solution: `Columns("B").Replace "Bird", "Parrot"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Findthenreplace()

    Dim myDataRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' set the range to 2nd column "B"
    Set myDataRng = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each cell In myDataRng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Bird") > 0 Then
            cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Bird", "Parrot")

        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```